# How to write junit with easymock in java?

Tags: java, junit, easymock

How to write a JUnit with EasyMock for getBoards method(Below mentioned in example).I tried but unable to cover the code by using JUnit with EasyMock. I have briefly explained in one more link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604031/how-to-write-test-method-for-void-method-in-junit-easymock-in-javalittle-diff-i"

```
public class DCI implements ...{
private Device device = null;
    private SnmpUtils snmp = null;
DCM(Device device){
 this.device = device;
}

@override
void openCommun(){
snmp = new SnmpUtils(device);
snmp.openSnmpComm();

}
// ---> How to write Junit test with easymock for this method?
public List<Board> getBoards(DeviceIdn deviceIdn) throws SnmpException {

        List<Board> boardList = new ArrayList<Board>();
        try {
        //BoardTableClass --> Below given
            BoardTable boardTable = new BoardTable(snmp);
            boardTable.readTable();

            for (int row = 0; row < boardTable.size(); row++) {

                String strBoardIndex = boardTable.getValue(row, BoardTable.BoardColumn.BoardIndex);
                String strBoardName = boardTable.getValue(row, BoardTable.BoardColumn.BoardName);
                String strBoardType = boardTable.getValue(row, BoardTable.BoardColumn.BoardType);
                int boardIndex = new Integer(strBoardIndex);
                BoardIdn boardIdn = new BoardIdn(deviceIdn, boardIndex);
                Board board = new Board(boardIdn);
                board.setName(strBoardName);
                board.setType(strBoardType);
                boardList.add(board);
            }
            logger.info(boardList.size());
        }
        //In handleException method , snmpException checked 
        catch (Exception e) {
            handleException(e);
        }

        return boardList;
    }
}
```

Comment: This layout isn't exactly conducive to mocking.  You're passing an instance variable into an object you're concretely constructing.  Unless you wanted to mock the instance variable, there's really very little to do with mocking.

Answer (score 0):

For void method mocking use `EasyMock.expectLastCall()`

For example you want to mock

```
  amimalService.saveOldAnimals(List<Animal> animals){} //present in AnimalService class
```

So your test case becomes

```
 animalService.saveOldAnimals(animals);
 EasyMock.expectLastCall();
```

Your void method is mocked.

In your case, just create DeviceIdn object and pass to getBoard method.

```
    getBoard(myDevice);
```

Understand what we need to mock and what not.I am not understanding your domain classes so unable to help you.But will help you to understand what need to mock.

For example, I have one which calls repository say `animalRepository.findByAge(int age)` which return `List<Animal>`

Now suppose in your getBoard() method if you have this method call so you can mock that method because for test case it is not good to get values from Database. So instead prepare your own values and return it to method whenever repository call is called.
So mocking for method is like this.

```
  EasyMock.expect(animalRepository.findByAge(12)).andReturn(amimalsList);
```

This animalsList is prepared by yourself in your test method in order to have test case working.

Comment: No..getBoards method is not void method.it returns List..i tried,but in second step, its coming out.its not going inside at all

Comment: No..getBoards method is not void method.it returns List..i tried,but in second step, its coming out.its not going inside at all  ..BoardTable boardTable = new BoardTable(snmp);
            boardTable.readTable(); after this its coming out

Comment: Thats why I am asking you whats BoardTable and what error you are getting. I am unable to help as I don't know your domain classes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604031/how-to-write-test-method-for-void-method-in-junit-easymock-in-javalittle-diff-i ... can you please c this link where I have explained in code.. actually BoardTable value which is getting from thirdparty source code.If u go that link, u can c.